# log4j: Single appender block to set log level not working for me

Tags: log4j, apache-zookeeper, appender

While trying to set the zookeeper log level to a value thats being set from an environment variable, the error contains the following message:

```
2018-10-17T00:45:32.658628+00:00 cherry-zk-node zookeeper: log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.TRACE
2018-10-17T00:45:32.658902+00:00 cherry-zk-node zookeeper: log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "TRACE".
2018-10-17T12:45:32.692874+00:00 cherry-zk-node zookeeper: log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.TRACEFILE
2018-10-17T00:45:32.693154+00:00 cherry-zk-node zookeeper: log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "TRACEFILE".
```

Attached below is the log4j.properties file

```
zookeeper.root.logger=$ENV_VARIABLE
zookeeper.console.threshold=$ENV_VARIABLE
zookeeper.log.file=zk.log
zookeeper.log.threshold=$ENV_VARIABLE
zookeeper.log.dir=.

log4j.rootLogger=${zookeeper.root.logger}

# CONSOLE  
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=${zookeeper.console.threshold}
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Set Appenders for ALL log levels from ENV variable
log4j.appender.WARN.Threshold=${zookeeper.console.threshold}
log4j.appender.INFO.Threshold=${zookeeper.console.threshold}
log4j.appender.ERROR.Threshold=${zookeeper.console.threshold}
log4j.appender.TRACE.Threshold=${zookeeper.console.threshold}

# Max log file size of 25MB
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.MaxFileSize=25MB
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, you should add appender named 'log4j.appender.TRACE' and 'log4j.appender.TRACEFILE'. Maybe you can remove 'TRACEFILE' from your ENV_VARIABLE first, seems a duplication.

Add

```
log4j.appender.TRACE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.TRACE.File=${zookeeper.tracelog.dir}/${zookeeper.tracelog.file}
log4j.appender.TRACE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.TRACE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} [myid:%X{myid}] - %-5p [%t:%C{1}@%L][%x] - %m%n
```

to the end of `log4j.properties`

Comment: Thanks @sel-fish for taking time to respond! I tried the suggestion and it is not yet able to identify "trace" supplied via the environment variable! It is somehow restricting to "debug" level even though the environment variable supplied is "trace". Is there a special treatment for only 'trace" mode in log4j?

Comment: @Keep i don't think there is a special treatment for 'trace' in log4j. can you share your ENV_VARIABLE ?

Comment: the environment variable set was as follows: ZOO_LOG4J_PROP="TRACE"

Comment: @Keep can you share more detail in the post ? including the commands you run. 'ZOO_LOG4J_PROP' seems not referred in the log conf.

Comment: Sorry @sel-fish. Oops, 'was a typo. Was meant to be ENV_VARIABLE="TRACE"